# Sql Server 2014 SSIS Import Wizard - how to insert GUID values

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a number of tables in my Sql Server 2014 database, which contain their primary keys defined as GUID type. I also have a number of Excel files, which I need to import into Sql Sql Server.
Is there a way to generate GUID for each inserter row during SSIS Import wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on [`Create a GUID column in SSIS`](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/02/create-guid-column-in-ssis.html):

1. You can put `Script Component Transformation` between source and destination.
2. Create new column
   Edit the Script Component and goto the Inputs and Outputs tab. Expand the Output 0 and add a new column. The column type should be uniqueidentifier `[DT_GUID]`.
3. Script Code (C#)

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Data;
   using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
   using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;


   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
   public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
   {
       public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
       {
           // Create a Globally Unique Identifier with SSIS
           Row.Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid(); 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This example assumes, that such SSIS import is implemented in code, as a VS project, as oppose to just using Import wizard GUI - correct?

Comment: Yes, you need SSIS package for it